# Carnivore vs carnivore

Tags: evolution

In Evolution (North Star games) if two carnivores attack each other can they both go extinct? Does player order matter?  Would player 1's carnivore live while player 2's dies off?  Do they eat each other at the same time?

Comment: The only way for an attacking and attacked species to both go extinct at the same time is if they both have 1 population and the species getting attacked has Horns.

Answer (score 12):

Feeding is entirely sequential:

> 2. Feeding Species
>
> **Beginning with the First Player and continuing clockwise**, each player must feed one of their Hungry species.

So if player 1's attack causes some other species to go extinct, then that species will not get a chance to feed regardless of who that species belonged to and whether it was a carnivore or not.

Also note that if Carnivore 1 attacks Carnivore 2, Carnivore 2 can't normally attack back even if it *does* survive because a predator must always have a strictly greater Body Size than its prey. That said, the Pack Hunting trait can create a scenario where this is possible.